# Why do I get blank OpenGL window when I plot points away from origin?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

This problem is part of a bigger project I am doing, but here is a simple example to display 5 points in a vertical line that I have coded. In the first example, notice that `m`, where the point to be plotted is stored is initialized to `float m[2] = {0.0f,0.0f}`.

Code:

```cpp
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
const int SPIRAL_SIZE = 200;

float m[2] = {0.0f, 0.0f};

void display()
{
    glPointSize(3.0);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        // Draw the point
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(m[0], m[1]);
        m[1] += 0.05;
        glEnd();
    }
    
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{     
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);    
    glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);    
    glutCreateWindow("Example");    
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output, which is expected:
[image: 5 points in a vertical line as expected]

but the moment I change the initialization of `m` to `m[2] = {10.0f, 10.0f}` I get a blank output window:
[image: Blank Output]

What I have already tried:

1. Removing the `glutSwapBuffers`.
2. Tried to start plotting at various other points.
3. Thinking this may be an issue with this particular file, I tried it on other projects of mine as well with same result. (Maybe I have made same mistakes in them as well).

**My project requires me to start plotting the points away from the origin. What am I doing wrong here, or what else do I need to do to accomplish that?**

Comment: The bottom left coordinate of the window is (-1, -1) and the top left coordinate is (1, 1). So (10, 10) is out of the window.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom left coordinate of the window is (-1, -1) and the top left coordinate is (1, 1). So (10, 10) is out of the window. You can change that with an [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection)  by using [`glOrtho`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml). e.g.:

```cpp
void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    float aspect = (float)width/(float)height;
 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();   
    glOrtho(-20.0 * aspect, 20.0 * aspect, -20.0, 20.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow("Example");
    
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```